# How to make an image to blink and overlap in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get this to look nice. This countdown is meant to go negative, once it does I'd like the skull and crossbones to be visible, and I'd want it to flash. I'm using this Javascript functionality...

```
var img = document.getElementById('Image1');
var interval = window.setInterval(function() {
    if (img.display == 'hidden'){
        img.style.visibility = 'visible';
    } else {
        img.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
}, 1000);
```

Once it's flashing, how do I get it to overlap the countdown `span`? 
http://jsfiddle.net/2Lufxs2t/3/

Comment: The code in the question has nothing to do with the code in the fiddle. The code in the fiddle is wrong in many ways, and throws exceptions (look in your console). Fix your code, post a matching question.

Comment: Your fiddle is not working. You should check the console to see what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ttphow9/) This worked great for me.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Countdown</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var seconds = 10;

function stopTimer() {
    clearTimeout(countdownTimer)
}

function floor(x) {
    return x | 0;
}

function pad(n) {
    if (n < 0) {
        n = -n;
    }
    if (n < 10) {
        return '0' + n.toString();
    }
    return n.toString();
}

function secondPassed() {
    var minutes = pad(floor(seconds / 60));
    if (seconds < 0) {
        minutes = '-' + minutes;
    }
    var remainingSeconds = pad(seconds % 60);

    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;
    if (seconds > 0) {
        seconds--;
        if (seconds > 8) {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
        } else if (seconds == 5) {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
        } else if (minutes == 0 & seconds == 0) {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";

            if (seconds%2 == 0) {
            document.getElementById('skull').style.display="none";  
            } 

            if (seconds%2 != 0) {
            document.getElementById('skull').style.display="block";             
            }


        }
    } else {

                if (seconds%2 == 0) {
            document.getElementById('skull').style.display="block";  
            } 

            if (seconds%2 != 0) {
            document.getElementById('skull').style.display="none";              
            }

        seconds--;
    }
}
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
     <img id="skull" src="http://s15.postimg.org/es5w3xpob/skull.gif"style="position:absolute;  z-index: -1;display:none;">
     <div style=" z-index:10;">
    <p align ="center">
    <span id="countdown" style="color:black; font-size: 450px; font-weight: bold;" ></span>
    </br>
    <button onclick="countdownTimer = setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000)">Start</button>
    <button onclick="stopTimer()">Stop</button>



        </p>

        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. After `var img = document.getElementById('Image1');` add `document.getElementById('countdown').style.display='none';` to hide your counter.
2. Remove your second interval: `var interval = window.setInterval(function(){`. Just leave the `if` that toggles the visibility as it is. The problem is that `secondPassed()` is running every second, and then your second interval is running again every second. So every second your inner interval runs twice and toggles itself.